# How to merge 3 DataFrames under certain conditions about date value in one of them in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I have 3 DataFrames in Python Pandas like below:

df1 (ID - int, TIME - datetime)

```
ID  | TIME
----|------
123 | 2022-07-18
333 | 2022-07-22
444 | 2022-07-19
... | ...
```

df2 (both int)

```
ID  | VALUE
----|------
123 | 556 
333 | 12  
444 | 88  
... | ...
```

df3 (both int)

```
ID  | TIME
----|------
123 | 11114 
333 | 2
444 | 23 
... | ...
```

And I need to make a merge:

- if TIME in df1 is < 2022-07-19 merge df1 with df2
- if TIME in df1 is >= 2022-07-19 merge df1 with df3

So as a result I need something like below:

```
ID  | TIME       | VALUE
----|------------|-------
123 | 2022-07-18 | 556
333 | 2022-07-22 | 2
444 | 2022-07-19 | 23
... | ...        | ...
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas? OF course merge by ID col :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are same index, same order `ID` in all 3 DataFrames use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['VALUE'] = np.where(df1['TIME'] < '2022-07-19', df2['VALUE'], df3['VALUE'])
```

If not use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['VALUE'] = np.where(df1['TIME'] < '2022-07-19', 
                        df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['VALUE']), 
                        df1['ID'].map(df3.set_index('ID')['VALUE']))
```